# Finding a clever way to set a threshold given a list of loss values

Tags: python, python-3.x, anomaly-detection

Assume I have a list of losses plotted in the following KDE plot:

[image]

If the goal is to spot the outliers, the best threshold would be clearly around `0.75`, where the value of density is the minimum possible (near zero), and it is at the beginning of the tail.

Given a list of loss values, how can I (as accurately as possible) set such a threshold at the beginning of the tail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest to `sort` the list of loss values.

Then it depends upon the number of values present.

Suppose there are `100` values in the list and you need to find the threshold up to `95%` accuracy, you can decide the threshold value after sorting the list and see beyond which point the last 5 values fall.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I presume you implied using a percentile, did you?

Comment: yes sort of.... !